# Is there a Bash one-liner to check that the output of three commands match?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to figure out some Bash-foo to check that the output of three different commands is identical. I can do this with several lines of a Bash script, I'm just wondering if what I want to do is possible in one line with some fancy shell I/O redirection.

What I want to do is check that an SSL certificate matches up with a particular key and certificate signing request.

The commands look like this:

```
openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in certificate.crt | openssl md5
openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in privateKey.key | openssl md5
openssl req -noout -modulus -in CSR.csr | openssl md5
```

If the key, cert, and csr match up, all three of those commands should spit out identical output, like: "(stdin)= 95ce143e8418cf8a4f7dd718983ed4eb".

Here's a prototype:

```
[[ $(echo -e "blah\nblah\nblah" | uniq | wc -l) -eq 1 ]]
```

But I can't get from there to the final product. This doesn't work:

```
[[ $(openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in certificate.crt | openssl md5 && openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in privateKey.key | openssl md5 && openssl req -noout -modulus -in CSR.csr | openssl md5 | uniq | wc -l) -eq 1 ]]
```

One problem is maybe that my prototype generates all three lines of output from one command, but the real thing uses `&&` a couple times.

Comment: You might want to ask this on SuperUser.stackexchange.com

Comment: For what it's worth, the question looks like a reasonable Stackoverflow question to me.  (One might take this one to either site.  Then again, I like bash-fu.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cmp -s <( cmd1) <(cmd2) && cmp -s <( cmd1) <(cmd3)`

Note that this construct executes cmd1 two times.

If you require single exec of each cmd, more complicated line would look something like:

`cmd1|tee >( cmp  -s <(cmd2) )|cmp -s <(cmd3)`

Also for the second one, checking the result is complicated (you have to check `PIPESTATUS` array)

Comment: Nice! Will you explain `<( ... )`? I've seen that [here](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/set-operations-in-unix-shell/) but I don't understand it.

Comment: `cmd1 <( cmd2)`  creates temp FIFO(named pipe) file and puts the stdout of  cmd2 in the FIFO, and the FIFO file is arg of cmd1

Comment: you can find more in the bash manual page (look for _named pipe_)

Comment: if you're gonna be using `cmp` then you should also have `diff3` installed (both part of _diffutils_), so you can simply do: `diff3 -A <(cmd1) <(cmd2) <(cmd3) && echo 'match'`

Comment: @c00kiemon5ter `diff3` is good tool for this purpose too, but not a POSIX standard, `cmp` is

Comment: The other thing is `sort` and `uniq` are not built-ins either

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant something like

```
((1 == $( ( echo 1 && sleep 1; echo 1 && sleep 1) | sort -u | wc -l ) ))
```

But it might be easier to do

```
x1=$( command1 )
x2=$( command2 )
x3=$( command3 )

if [[ $x1 == $x2 && $x2 == $x3 ]] ; then
    echo The same.
fi
```

Edit:
This form should work as well, but reduce the number of stored variables.

```
x1=$(command1)
[[ $x1 == $(command2) && $x1 == $(command3) ]] && echo match
```

Comment: +1 for using only shell builtins, but only the first VAR is needed.  The other commands can compare directly to it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're piping only the last command "sub-pipeline" into `uniq`. Try this:

```
[[ $( { openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in certificate.crt | openssl md5 && openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in privateKey.key | openssl md5 && openssl req -noout -modulus -in CSR.csr | openssl md5; } | uniq | wc -l) -eq 1 ]]
```

The curly braces make the three "sub-pipelines" act as if together they are one command as far as `uniq` is concerned, analogously to your `echo` prototype.